# onLongPress triggers instead of onPress for single tap

Tags: react-native, touchableopacity, onpress

I have a card item with `TouchableOpacity` which has both `onPress` and `onLongPress`. When I intend to perform `onPress` action by taping on the record `onLongPress` gets triggered. This is happening only when remote debugger is enabled. And this is happening both in emulator and real device.

Issue reported in [github](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/4944) as well long back, but no solution as of now.

Any help is appreciated to prevent this behavior.Thank you.

Comment: it has issue when app is running in debug mode, while it is OK when app runs in release and without debug mode. (I've same issue while debugging mode, simply dismiss and work with it)